# Count Distinct IDs in a date range given a start and end time

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table like this

| id | start_date | end_date | location | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | MO | mobile |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | MO | mobile |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | AZ | laptop |
| 3 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 | AZ | mobile |
| 3 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 | AZ | mobile |
| 3 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 | AZ | mobile |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | CA | laptop |
| 4 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | CA | mobile |
| 5 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | CA | laptop |

I want to return the number of unique IDs by location and type of an arbitrary date range.

The issue I have is that there are multiple repeating lines covering similar dates, like the first two rows above.

For example, a date range of 2022-01-02 and 2022-01-03 would return

| location | type | count distinct ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AZ | laptop | 1 |
| AZ | mobile | 1 |
| CA | laptop | 2 |
| CA | mobile | 1 |
| MO | mobile | 1 |

I first tried creating a list of dates in like

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE('Europe/London'), INTERVAL 3 MONTH),MONTH), DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE('Europe/London'), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS cal_date)
```

and using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id,start_date,end_date)` to expose only unique rows.

But I was only able to return the number of unique IDs for each day, rather than looking at the full date range as a whole.

I then tried joining to the same cte to return a unique row for each date, so something like

date | id | start_date | end_date | location | type

Where the columns from the first table above are duplicated for each date but this would require generating a huge number of rows to then further work with.

What is the correct way to acheive the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way is

```
select location, type, count(distinct id) distinct_ids
from your_table, unnest(generate_date_array(start_date, end_date)) effective_date
where effective_date between '2022-01-02' and '2022-01-03'
group by location, type
```

with output (if applied to sample data in your question)

[image]